# Magento: Settings has not been loaded. Used default settings Wrong config file size connect.cfg please save Settings again

Tags: magento

I am receiving a following error

Settings has not been loaded. Used default settings
Wrong config file size connect.cfg please save Settings again

in magento connect. I tried to delete files and did every possible thing, but the issue is not getting resolved. Please help me with possible solution guys. Also the extensions are not getting installed because of this and we are not able to solve problems.

We are using magento 1.9

Comment: you need execute `chmod 0777 downloader` that magento-connect can write the connect.cfg file. After install I recomend to revert it back to `chmod 0444 downloader`

Comment: Hello Sir, I tried the following thing. But it is giving me not found error.

Comment: Do you have `downloader` folder inside of root magento? you need to chmod it with `rwxrwxrwx`

Comment: Hello Sir, I am changing the permission through file manager file permission. Once i change the permission to 777 it gives me 404 not found error for magento connect.

Comment: Do you have `downloader` folder inside of root magento?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you click settings and click save as this flag will not clear until you do so. I was pulling my hair out with this as I chmod'd the files and chown'd the directory's but it was still showing the error. So once the file and folder permissions are set correctly go to the Magento Connect manager click the settings tab and click save settings then go back to extensions tab and the error will now be gone.

Tony Merlin

Answer (score 1):

When you are in magento connect manager and you get this error
*

> Settings has not been loaded. Used default settings

*
Click on magento conect manager Settings tab (top left) and select Use Custom Permissions --> YES and default should be 777 for folders and 666 for files. Deployment Type --> Local Filesystem and then hit SAVE SETTINGS.

The problem should be solved. At least that's how I solved mine when I got this error.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure the /dowloader folder permissions are set to 777 and you can also chown the folder with the apache user. That worked for me. I have done:

```
chmod 777 -R /downloader/

chown www-data:www-data -R /downloader/
```

replace www-data with your apache user.
I've done this and worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Can you help me do that, because i think changing apache user will create problems in terms of security & also when i am changing the permission to 777, it is giving me page not found error

Comment: There is no security issue if you change the downloader folder owner to apache, because apache needs to read that folder. If apache is not able to read that folder, it will not work. Depends on the rights and the configuration of your apache, the "page not found" error can be shown. Check the error.log and let me know what error you get there.

Comment: @AnishJain usually it's in /var/log/apache.log, depends on your system settings. I think you should ask a system administrator to have a look if you are unexperimented with servers

Comment: We are using dedicated server with WHM and Cpanel. Our website is hosted using cpanel. If anyone is ready to solve my problem, we are ready to pay also for getting rid of this bloody problem. We are not able to find any resolution on any forum.

Comment: @AnishJain I am offering myself to help you solving this issue. I don't need any  money, I'll gladly help you if I can. Just contact me at (same nickname like here) at yahoo com.

Answer (score 0):

It's a well known issue.

1. Check if the file named "connect.cfg" hasn't been modified (for
   exemple: when I get this issue, the file has nothing into it, every
   parameters have been removed and the size is 0kb)
2. Take a backup of this file and overwrite the existing
3. The issue should be solved know

For info about the access rights, I have :

- 2775 for the folder "downloader"
- 0664 for the file "connect.cfg

Answer (score 0):

`chown apache /var/www/ -hR` will solve this problem.